# Erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\adocao\backend\valida.php on line 32

Tags: php

Pessoal não estou conseguindo achar o erro por favor alguém me ajuda:

```
<?php
session_start();    
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");    
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))) 
{
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = $senha;

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if (isset($resultado)) 
    {           
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];

        if ($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1")
        {
            header("Location: administrativo.php");
            exit;
        }
        else ($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2")
        {
            header("Location: colaborador.php");
            exit;
        }

    }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    else {
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
} 

else
{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha não preenchidos";
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: qual é a linha 32?

Comment: header("Location: colaborador.php");

Comment: Emmanuel, seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Parece que sua pergunta está incompleta, dê mais informações sobre o seu projeto para que possamos te ajudar. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre como funciona o site, veja o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e dê uma olhada sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @bio isso é um erro de digitação, não precisa mais informação além do código e do erro retornado. Só que parece que o código que esta na pergunta não é o mesmo do arquivo, porque se a linha 32 é a `header("Location: colaborador.php");` não é nela o erro, pois contém o ponto e virgula.. Só um detalhe que não é necessário `exit;` quando se esta fazendo um redirecionamento. Votei para fechar a pergunta, olhe bem seus arquivos e veja aonde está faltando **;**

Comment: @wmsouza Achei a pergunta vaga e mal estruturada tanto em título quanto em conteúdo, afinal, nem o número da linha ele havia informado, mas não vou estender meus argumentos.

Comment: No titulo, esta o erro que no final tem `line 32`.

Comment: @wmsouza e qual linha que é no código? Ele teve que informar depois...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jovem, o erro é que você colocou uma expressão no `else`. Não existe expressão no `else`.

Caso necessite utilizar uma segunda expressão condicional, utilize `elseif`.

Exemplo:

```
if (expressao) {
    // bla
} elseif (outra_expressao) {
    //ble
}
```

Comment: [Estruturas de Controle](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Parecia ter resolvido mas agora está redirecionando para a página: localhost/adocao/backend/loginusuario.php mas essa página só existe na raiz.

Comment: @EmmanuelSiqueira nesse caso, se o erro é outro, você precisa fazer outra pergunta no site.

Comment: @EmmanuelSiqueira verifique a lógica do seu código, caso tenha algum outro erro, abra outra pergunta. Se a resposta atendeu seu problema em específico, coloque ela como Aceita. Leia mais [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Troque o else por elseif

```
if ($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1")
{
    header("Location: administrativo.php");
    exit;
 }
 elseif ($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2")
 {
    header("Location: colaborador.php");
    exit;
 }
```

Comment: Parecia ter resolvido mas agora está redirecionando para a página: http://localhost/adocao/backend/loginusuario.php mas essa página só existe na raiz.